# Error: ErorAndroid/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: opencv, android-ndk

I am  using android Ndk in my project , whenever i want to build my project it shows this error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'. Process 'command
>   'E:/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit
>   value 2

i have created android.mk and application.mk

**Application.mk**

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-16
```

**android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
C:\OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk
#opencv
OPENCVROOT:= C:\OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LLB_TYPE:=SHARED
include ${OPENCVROOT}/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk


LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=com_example_abr_ndkopencvtest2_OpencvNativeClass.cpp

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
LOCAL_MODULE := MyOpencvLibs

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**build.gradle file**

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.abr.ndkopencvtest2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    sourceSets.main{
        jni.srcDirs = []
    }
    task ndkBuild(type: Exec,description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK'){
        commandLine "E:/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build.cmd",
                'NDK_PROJECT_PATH = build/intermediates/ndk',
                'NDK_LIBS_OUT=src/main/jniLibs',
                'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
                'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk'
    }
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile){
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':openCVLibrary249')
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have solved my issue i had no issues with android.mk or android.application , it was my fault i did some mistakes with my cpp file and .h files so now its working correctly

Comment: Please define the mistake @Abubakar

Answer (score 0):

Check you added in gradle – local properties

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk = true
```

Then after this, when you **build project** you got **BUILD SUCCESSFUL** message. 
And for detailed process flow, make sure that you correctly followed the steps to succesfully setup an Android 
NDK build environment.